# int(blah) giving different answer from (blah) as int

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Newbie ActionScript 3 question: why does

```
(Math.sqrt((r * r - (r - i) * (r - i)) as Number) * 2) as int
```

give me a different result from

```
int(Math.sqrt((r * r - (r - i) * (r - i)) as Number) * 2)
```

Comment: Well... what 2 results do you get?

Comment: 9.59... without any casting to int, 9 with the second one, and 0 for the first one.

Comment: I did some more testing, and apparently (9 as int), (9.5 as Number), and (int(9.5)) give the correct results, but (9.5 as int) results in null. Why would this be the case?

Comment: Hmm! This user had a similar problem: http://www.flexer.info/2008/01/11/cast-to-int-issue/

I was under the impression that the two casting methods were nearly equivalent. Is this even mentioned anywhere in the ActionScript documentation?!

Comment: This question really does need more up votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `as` operator is a direct cast, whereas `int()` implicitly finds the floor of the Number (note that it doesn't actually call `Math.floor`, though). The [Adobe docs for `as`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#as) say it checks that the "first operand is a member of the data type specified by the second operand." Since 9.59 is not representable as an int, the `as` cast fails a returns null, while `int()` first finds the floor of the number, then casts it to int.

You could do `Math.floor(blah) as int`, and it should work, though it would be slower. Assuming you want a rounded int, `Math.round(blah) as int` would be more correct, but `int(blah + .5)` would be fastest and round correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The as operator is not much as a cast, more something like:

i is int ? int : null;

This is confusing as hell. It checks if the variable is of that type, if it is, the variable is returned, else you'd get null (0 for an int).